# How to rearrange (move) Extensions MS Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge, extension

I've got a lot of Extensions in my MS Edge browser (windows 10) More than will fit on the Menu bar

How can I move some of them up to the Menu?

Answer (score 0):

Best option so far:

1. Choose which Extensions will go on the Menu bar, using the eye icon[image]
2. Move them horizontally along the menu to arrange them.
3. There seems to be no way to change the order of the Extensions list. (lower right of the screenshot above)

Comment: "There seems to be no way to change the order of the Extensions list" they are sorted in alpha order